# Can't give anchor link to logo

Tags: html, css, href, anchor

I am currently making a website and I have put my logo in like this:

```css
header .logo a {
  background-image: url(Images/FRANKEN\ DEVELOPMENT\ FATTER\ AND\ OTHER\ COLOR2.png);
  background-size: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  text-indent: -9999999px;
  width: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  top: -21px;
  left: 25px;
  filter: contrast(2);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li class="logo"><a>Franken Development Logo</a></li>
      <li><a class="categories" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="categories" href="#">Websites</a></li>
    </ul>
  <nav>
<header>
```

As you can see, my text is out of frame with text-indent: -9999999px;

But know, when I make it a link (the logo), it will not work because the text will become a link (which is far away from vision) and not the image.

How do I make it so my logo goes to index.html? And not the text, representing the logo.

-Ian

Comment: there is no href attribute on your link, so nowhere to go and nothing to click. `<li class="logo"><a href="index.html">Franken Development Logo</a></li>`will work . - Beside I doubt that Franken Development Logo is the title of index.html :) looks like an alt value for the logo if it was an <img> . ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a logo and text to represent your company name, you can wrap both in an anchor tag.

Examples:

With visible text:

```
<a href="/index.html">
    <img src="/image/path/here" aria-hidden="true">
    <p>Franken Development</p>
</a>
```

With alt text instead of visible text:

```
<a href="/index.html">
    <img src="/image/path/here" alt="Franken Development logo">
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Href for the image itself.

```css
header .logo a {
  background-image: url(Images/FRANKEN\ DEVELOPMENT\ FATTER\ AND\ OTHER\ COLOR2.png);
  background-size: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  text-indent: -9999999px;
  width: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  top: -21px;
  left: 25px;
  filter: contrast(2);
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li class="logo"><a href="#">Franken Development Logo</a></li>
      <li><a class="categories" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="categories" href="#">Websites</a></li>
    </ul>
    <nav>
      <header>
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_href.asp)

Comment: This solution depends on JavaScript, which means it'll fail for users who have JavaScript disabled or in situations where JavaScript has failed to load. <a> tags in HTML allow you to pass a `href`, and we should use default HTML behaviour before looking at JS solutions.

Comment: Your updated example adds a `href` attribute to a list (`li`) item, which isn't valid. The `href` attribute needs to be added to the `a` tag.

Comment: then why not just make the anchor clickable?